# getLoginStatus returns status unknown when trying to logout from Facebook using Facebook JS SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a localhost website, where I've implemented login via Facebook using Facebook C# SDK.

**Startup configuration class**:

```js
    public class ExternalLoginConfig
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = ConfigSettings.FacebookAppId,
                AppSecret = ConfigSettings.FacebookAppSecret,
                Scope = { "email" },
                Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
                        var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

                        var result = facebookClient.Get("me", new { fields = "email,first_name,last_name" }) as JsonObject;

                        string email = null;
                        string firstName = null;
                        string lastName = null;

                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            email = result.ContainsKey("email") ? (string) result["email"] : null;
                            firstName = result.ContainsKey("first_name") ? (string) result["first_name"] : null;
                            lastName = result.ContainsKey("last_name") ? (string) result["last_name"] : null;
                        }

                        if (firstName != null)
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, firstName));
                        }
                        if (lastName != null)
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, lastName));
                        }
                        if (email != null)
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email));
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    OnApplyRedirect = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&auth_type=reauthenticate");
                    }
                }
            };
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
        }
    }
```

**Actions form Authentication controller**:

```js
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public virtual ActionResult Login(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session.RemoveAll();

        return new ExternalLoginResult(provider,
            Url.Action("LoginCallback", "Oauth", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LoginCallback(string returnUrl, string error)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        User user = null;
        string userName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string firstName = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
        string lastName = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Surname);
        string email = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        string externalProviderName = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
        string externalProviderKey = loginInfo.Login.ProviderKey;

        var externalAuthenticationInfo = new ExternalAuthenticationInfo()
        {
            Username = userName,
            Email = email,
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
            ExternalProviderName = externalProviderName,
            ExternalProviderKey = externalProviderKey
        };

        var loginResult = userProvider.ExternalLogin(externalProviderKey, email, out user);

        switch (loginResult)
        {
            case LoginResult.Success:
            {
                AuthenticationHelper.SetAuthenticatedUserId(user.ID);
                break;
            }
            case LoginResult.NotRegistered:
            {
                var registerResult = userProvider.Register(userName, email, null, externalAuthenticationInfo);

                if (registerResult.IsValid)
                {
                    AuthenticationHelper.SetAuthenticatedUserId(registerResult.Result.ID);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

**Facebook JS SDK initialization**:

```js
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '@ConfigSettings.FacebookAppId',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.4'
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I'm attempting to log a user out of facebook with the Facebook JS SDK, however calling:

```js
    FB.getLoginStatus(function facebookLogoutCallback(facebookResponse) {
        if (facebookResponse.status !== 'connected') {
            return;
        }

        FB.logout(facebookLogoutCallback);
    });
```

leads to status `unknown` instead of `connected`, which is returned in `facebookResponse` object. I've also tried to call `FB.logout()` without `if` statement, but it didn't work.

Maybe you can say, that this behavior is caused by unauthorized user status, but after server side login the user is actually logged in: on my website and Facebook too.

Comment: what is the real fix for that ?

Answer (score 11):

It seems that there's a bug currently in the FB.logout function. After calling it the user can not be logged into this App again using the JS SDK because the FB.login function returns
Object { status="unknown",  authResponse=null}

EDIT:
Found that there's a cookie called "fblo_*" created after FB.logout() which seems to be the reason for this. I can't say exactly why it's there and what it does, but deleting it makes the login work again.

Therefor I created a small script that looks for this cookie and deletes it just before I call FB.login() which you probably want to call in a click event  (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.5).

```
function delete_cookie(name) 
{
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/';
}


var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
{
    if(cookies[i].split("=")[0].indexOf("fblo_") != -1)
        delete_cookie(cookies[i].split("=")[0]);
}
```

Comment: There's a small bug where some `fblo_` cookies that you split will have leading whitespace. I use jQuery `$.trim` to remove that whitespace.

Comment: I arrived to this conclussion also. Nice to see that there are other people having the same issue. No idea of why it is happening though...