# Facebook getLoginStatus() returning {authResponse: null, status: "unknown"} on page refresh after login

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to implement login/logout functionality using the javascript Facebook SDK and have hit a wall - think it might be a bug in the SDK, but I want to check that I'm actually implementing everything right first.

Demo of implementation following facebook guidelines: [demo1](http://ec2-34-248-33-121.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test_facebook.html)

On logging in for the first time and refreshing the page, everything works as expected, but on logging out, then trying to log back in, getLoginStatus() returns {authResponse: null, status: "unknown"} every time, even after logging in again.

Demo where I don't use FB.logout: [demo2](http://ec2-34-248-33-121.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test_facebook_logout_changed.html)
but instead call the following to revoke application permissions. This works, but means the user has to re-authorise the app on every call to login.

```
    FB.api("/me/permissions", "delete", function(response){
      render_page_logout(response);
   });
```

Demo of implementation where I delete the "fblo_" cookie after calling `FB.logout()`, can be found at the same domain, page `test_facebook_delete_cookie.html` (I can't post more than two links due to having <10 reputation), this was advised in another stackoverflow question encountering a similar problem - but this doesn't work for me.

I think this is a bug with facebook, but can't seem to find a workaround which allows a user to: login -> refresh the page and still be logged in -> logout -> log back in and loop back to the start without having to reauthorize app permissions every time.

Comment: Link to demo of deleting cookie: http://ec2-34-248-33-121.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test_facebook_delete_cookie.html
as advised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725123/getloginstatus-returns-status-unknown-when-trying-to-logout-from-facebook-using

Comment: The demo is not testable for us, because the app is in development mode. However, in browser console I see _“Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.”_

Comment: Ah yes, sorry - I've just made it public. Can you reproduce the errors now?

Comment: I don’t see any of the console.log output in Firebug - but it seems to work, in that it shows the "login/sign-up" and "logout" links alternate. After I log out, I need to login to Facebook again the next time the login popup shows.

Comment: (on test_facebook.html) If you login, then logout, then log back in again, then refresh the page, does it stay logged in (the logout button shows).

Comment: Yeah, you’re right, that doesn’t seem to work. Try initializing the JS SDK with `status: true`, that makes it check again with Facebook, otherwise it will just use a cached result. If that doesn’t help, try calling FB.getLoginStatus with the second parameter set to true (also to circumvent caching.) Does that change anything?

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything: http://ec2-34-248-33-121.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test_facebook_no_cache.html